# Mongo db search like query, but with criteria in the subarray

Tags: mongodb, search, sub-array, database

Hi I have this kind of object.

```
{
    "_id" : "wavQwJn5ZGQw2sTqb",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-12-15T13:55:21.526Z"),
    "services" : {
        "password" : {
            "bcrypt" : "passhash"
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [ 
                {
                    "when" : ISODate("2015-12-15T13:56:48.837Z"),
                    "hashedToken" : "tokenhash"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "profile" : {
        "name" : "First Name LastName"
    },
    "emails" : [ 
        {
            "address" : "myemail1@domain.com",
            "verified" : false
        },
        {
            "address" : "myemail2@domain.com",
            "verified" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to search for users by their email or profile name, but this email is in subarray and each element there is an little object and profile is an object, so I got really confused here.

For example if email was in the main object I can do this:

```
let selector = {
    'email' : { '$regex' : '.*' + searchString || '' + '.*', '$options' : 'i' },
}

Meteor.users.find(selector, options);
```

but unfortunaly is in subarray, so if someone can explain how I can do that would be great. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can search email using aggregation framework.

**$unwind** operator helps you.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:'$emails'},{$match:{'emails.address':{$eq:'myemail1@domain.com'}}}]);
```

Document for reference: [MongoDB unwind docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)